# In PHP, is it possible to take web page screenshots in memory?

Tags: php, screenshot

By "in memory", I mean that the screenshot won't be written to a file.

The requirement is to generate thumbnails of a web page that will be stored in the database.  I know that saving images in the database is not recommended, but we might not have write permissions in our server, so we are exploring this option.

If it's possible, how is it done?

Comment: A couple of notes: 1, stored to database doesn't mean it's not written to a file. It just means it's stored in the database's file system, likely on disk, rather than the standard file system. 2, do you already have the screenshots, or are you asking about how to generate them, too? It's not very possible with just PHP, as PHP is not an HTML/CSS renderer. You generally need a browser AND a display (at least a virtual X/VNC display) to create a screenshot.

Comment: @Alex JL: You really don't need a display to generate screenshots. There are tools that will render directly to an image, and after all, even a browser needs to generate an image in memory before displaying it.

Comment: @casablanca That's good, I looked into the various webkit renderers but they all seemed pretty sklonky last I checked. I'll have to check out the ones you recommend. I've had the best luck with just starting a real browser on Xvfb.

Comment: @Alex JL -- I do understand that about databases vs files.  It's just that I myself (or the web server user) might not have the privileges to write to file.  I won't be the sysad of the would-be server, and the sysad might not grant me my requests that easily.  Having a database set-up for me is, on the other hand, pretty much a sure thing.

Comment: My current solution uses CutyCapt, which requires the Qt Framework, which in turn has a built-in Webkit engine. It works pretty well on WinXP, Mac OS X and Ubuntu.  For Linux, it still requires Xvfb (or some other virtual display).

Comment: Sure, I was just pointing out that it's about databases vs. native filesystem, rather than files vs. memory (RAM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require a webpage renderer written in PHP, and as far as I know, there is no library that does this. There are however several command-line tools that can do this ([CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/) is one example), but they *will* write to a file.

As regards write permissions, you might be able to write to `/tmp` and then do a pass-through via PHP.

Comment: I'm using CutyCapt during development.  I was just presented possible issues I might run into when deploying to production.  I'll see if `/tmp` will be available.  Thanks!